# Why do we need $X$ to be compact in the definition of the topology of uniform convergence?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> If $(Y,\rho)$ is a metric space and $X$ is compact, then the set $C(X,Y)$ is equipped with a metric $\mu$ thus:
>   $$\mu(f_1, f_2) = \sup_{x \in X} \rho(f_1(x), f_2(x)), f_1, f_2 \in C(X,Y)$$
>
> Definition. The topology $\tau_1$ as determined by the metric $\mu$ is called the topology of uniform convergence.

Why do we need $X$ to be compact?
To define the metric isn't compactness of $Y$ is sufficient?

Comment: May I know the reason for negative voting?

Comment: Probably because you posted a picture of text instead of retyping it, or because you used a completely wrong tag, or because your title wasn't very informative. Compare your first version of the question with the one after my edit, which one would you find more useful/interesting if you hadn't been the one to post it?

Comment: Note that in your definition you did not require that $Y$ is compact.

Comment: So where do we need compactness of $X$?

Comment: And if $Y$ was not compact, can we take supremum over $/rho$

Answer (score 1):

Actually the definition

$$ \mu(f_1, f_2)  = \sup_{x\in X} \rho(f_1(x), f_2(x))$$

make sense whenever one of $X$ and $Y$ are compact. If both $X$, $Y$ are non-compact, then supremum might not exist.

However, it is usually more convenient to let $Y$ to be non-compact, which include the space of continuous function $C(X, \mathbb R)$.